# Greatest integer function: why $-3 < [x] < 2 \implies -2 \leq x < 2$

Tags: functions

While solving a domain problem,I got a step while solving that problem which is:

\begin{align*}
\implies & -3 < [x] < 2\\
\implies & -2 \leq x < 2
\end{align*}
My doubt is how do you get the above inequality of $x$ from $[x]$?  This should be one of the properties of greatest integer functions but I'm not able to grasp.  Please help.

Comment: $x\in [-2,2)$ is not it?

Comment: Hint. Since $[x]$ is an integer, $-3 < [x] < 2$ implies that $-2\leq [x]\le 1$. Now recall that $[x]\leq x<[x]+1$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $[x]$ is an integer, so in the given range it can be $-2,-1,0,1$. For every integer $m$, you have$$[x]=m\Longleftrightarrow m\le x<m+1$$Thus, for $m=-2$, you get $x\in[-2,-1)$. For $m=-1$, you get $x\in[-1,0)$ and so on. Note that $m=-2$ **or** $m=-1$ indicates that we are supposed to take the union of $[-2,-1)$ and $[-1,0)$. Finally you get$$x\in[-2,1)\cup[-1,0)\cup[0,1)\cup[1,2)=[-2,2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Greatest integer function is defined as

> Greatest integer function denoted by $y=[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to x.

$$[x]=n\;\forall\;n-1\le x<n, n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

To answer your question $$[x]=-3\;\forall\;x\in[-3,-2) \\ 
[x]=-2\;\forall\;x\in[-2,-1) \\ 
[x]=-1\;\forall\;x\in[-1,0)$$

Do you see it?

Comment: I get what you say but how do you get values of x from the above inequality of [x]?

Comment: $[x]>-3$ so the $[x]\ge-2$.

Comment: Check your definition for the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the greatest integer function $[x]: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is defined to be the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.  For example,
\begin{align*}
[3] & = 3\\
[\pi] & = 3\\
\left[\frac{7}{2}\right] & = 3\\
[2.19] & = 2\\
[-5.4] & = -6\\
[-6] & = -6
\end{align*}
If $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $[x] = n$, then $n \leq x < n + 1$, as shown in the graph below.

[image: greatest_integer_function_graph]

We wish to find those $x$ such that $-3 < [x] < 2$.  As Robert Z pointed out in the comments, since $[x]$ is an integer, this is equivalent to saying that $-2 \leq [x] \leq 1$.
\begin{align*}
[x] = -2 & \implies -2 \leq x < -1\\
[x] = -1 & \implies -1 \leq x < 0\\
[x] = 0 & \implies 0 \leq x < 1\\
[x] = 1 & \implies 1 \leq x < 2
\end{align*}
from which we conclude that $-3 < [x] < 2 \implies -2 \leq x < 2$.